# Book on Applications of Diophantine Equations in Science

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations, applications

Please suggest a book on applications of Diophantine equations in physics, chemistry, and biology. This book should be suitable to introduce this subject to students who are not mathematics specialists.

Answer (score 2):

"OP" Can look up book by 'Stephen Wolfram' called 'A new kind of science'. It has stuff on Diophantine equations related to different branches of science in the notes section. The book can be availed of at the local library or purchased as hardcover or E-book. Also a summary is available on line. The links are given below:

https://www.wolframscience.com

http://store.wolfram.com/view/book/ISBN1579550088.str?Qualifier=COMM

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stephen-wolfram-a-new-kind-of-science/id390711826

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any such book, but you may find [this article](http://ijmaa.in/v5n2-b/217-222.pdf) interesting.